# Unable to get material UI Lab CDN

Tags: material-ui

I am developing material ui application using material ui core CDN . In my application I want to use slider component from material UI lab .
Material UI core's CDN is provided in material UI web site but they did not provide CDN for material UI Lab. If there is material UI Lab CDN then please provide an example .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please include a reproducible, isolated programing problem in your question. In your case, you might be good to go using JSFIDDLE.

Answer (score 0):

you need to added @material-ui/core with @material-ui/lab, so it's your choice how you add it with npm install or cdn.

Please find the relevant links below:

@material-ui/lab npm package reference: [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@material-ui/lab)

@material-ui/lab cdn reference: [Here](https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/@material-ui/lab)

Regards :)

Comment: CDN https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@material-ui/lab@3.0.0-alpha.30/index.min.js  does not have all material ui lab content . Unable to understand which URL need to use.

Comment: above is the minified file.. thats why you can see the content.. for details visit https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@material-ui/lab@3.0.0-alpha.30/index.js to get the silder..